# Detect when USB device was disconnected using usbd_core.c

Tags: c, embedded, usb

So working on an embedded system I have a USB drive that is used to charge the device as well as reading some data.

Using `usbd_core.c` I can check the status,

- when there's nothing connected the status is `4` (`USBD_STATE_SUSPENDED`).
- As soon as I connect something the status changes to `1` (`USBD_STATE_DEFAULT`).
- But when I disconnect it the status doesn't change, it continues to be `1` (`USBD_STATE_DEFAULT`).

Is it supposed to be like this or I am missing something?

I have also tried `USBD_Stop()` and `USBD_Start()` to see if it makes any difference but still the status doesn't change when I disconnect it.

Any ideas?

Comment: "usbd_core.c" from where?  The file is by no means universal or standard, and the same filename may be used in more than one implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB specification defines six USB device states:

- **Attached**: the device is attached to the USB but is not powered by the USB.
- **Powered**: the device is attached to the USB and has been powered but has not yet received any reset request.
- **Default**: the device is attached to the USB. It is powered and reset, but no unique address has been assigned to it.
- **Address**: the device is attached to the USB, it is powered and reset and has had a unique address assigned to it.
- **Configured**: the device is already in address state and configured. It is not in suspend state.
- **Suspended**: the device is attached and configured, but has not detected any activity on the bus for at least 3 ms.

As you can see *suspended* requires an attached and configured device, however also note that *all* of these states require an attached device and cannot apparently be used to imply a physically detached device.

Disconnection is a low-level event from the USB controller - your API may provide a callback for such events.